# Не меняется URL - JSP

Tags: java, url, jsp, servlet

Есть стартовая страница index.jsp. На ней форма авторизации/регистрации.
За авторизацию отвечает сервелт Auth соответственно при нажатии на кнопку идёт обращение к этому сервлету методом post. Он отрабатывает но проблема в другом. 
Есть домашняя страница, куда попадают юзеры после успешной авторизации - home.jsp(home). Соответственно в сервлете Auth происходит переадресация, если юзер прошел авторизацию. А проблема в том что после нажатия кнопки авторизации url адрес становится таким: http://localhost:8080/mysite/Auth. И так даже если авторизация не успешная и даже если мы перешли в home.jsp. Этот адрес не меняется.

Прописал в web.xml так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>mysite</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Auth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.tsyklop.mysite.Auth</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Auth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/auth</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

index изменился. Вместо index.jsp в адресной строке теперь index. но другое не поменялось.

Что не так?

Код сервела Auth:

```
package ru.tsyklop.mysite;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Auth
 */
@WebServlet("/Auth")
public class Auth extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Auth() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //out.append("POST!");

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;

        String Email = request.getParameter("email");
        String Pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        if(Email.equals("test@gmail.com") && Pass.equals("123456"))
        {
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("home");
        } else {
            //response.sendRedirect("index");
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index");
            request.setAttribute("error", "Email or password incorrect. Try again!");
        }
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Суть проблемы в методе `request.getRequestDispatcher(String path).forward` - он незаметно для пользователя перенаправляет **запрос** по новому пути.передача управления происходит в контейнере и браузер не участвует.

А вот использование метода `response.sendRedirect(String path);` вернет заголовок обратно клиенту и обяжет его (клиент или браузер) послать новый запрос уже по указанному адресу (что конечно отразиться в строке URL).

Comment: Проблема в том что Dispatcher используется для того что бы изменялись атрибуты которые я задаю. Это ошибка при неверном логине, к примеру. Если я буду использовать sendRedirect то setAtrbute срабатывать не будет. А мне он нужен.

Спасибо.

Comment: @Александр Лемягов проводите валидацю пользователя  в фильтре на подлете к сервлету home

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов и вы и не будете зависит от URL

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о чём идёт речь про фильтр...
Скажу что сделал куки. Если юзер не авторизован его будет переадресовывать на index.

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов  Имеется в виду реализация интерфейса javax.servlet.Filter Шаблон данного инерфейса наверняка представлен в вашей IDE.Для полноты картины рекомендую прочитать что такое слушатель (в контексте web разработки) А касательно пенечек стоит задуматься что будет делать ваше приложение если они отключены у пользователя (Хотя если это ваше первое,не боевое приложение то о таком и не стоит и задумываться).